# Internal equality for Eq-fibrations

Tags: logic, category-theory, type-theory, categorical-logic

In Jacob's *Categorical logic and Type Theory* in relation to *fibrations with equality* the author gives the following definition:

> ...call two morphisms of Eq-fibrations $(K,H),(H',K') \colon p \to q$ between two Eq-fibrations $p \colon \mathbb E \to \mathbb B$ and $q \colon \mathbb D \to \mathbb A$ equivalent if
>   1) $H=H'$ and on objects $K=K' \colon \text{Obj}(\mathbb B) \to \text{Obj}(\mathbb A)$;
>   2) $K(u)$ and $K'(u)$ are internally equal in $q$, for each morphism $u$ in $\mathbb B$.

This definition troubles me for the following reason.

Assume $(H,K)$ and $(H',K')$ are as above (i.e. they are an equivalent pair of morphisms of Eq-fibrations) and let $u$ be a morphism of $\mathbb B$.

Since $p$ is a fibration, and we assume that all the fibers are not empty categories (assumption reasonable for instance for the classifying fibration of an equational theory),  we have a cartesian lifting of $u$, so we have a morphism $v$ in $\mathbb E$ such that $p(v)=u$.

Since by hypothesis $H=H'$ we should have 
$$q \circ H(v)=q \circ H'(v)$$ 
and since $(H,K)$ and $(H',K')$ are morphism of fibrations
$$K\circ p(v) = K' \circ p(v)$$
hence
$$K(u) = K'(u)\ .$$

Since we made no assumption on $u$, with the exception of being in the image of $p$ which should hold in all classifying fibration (if I am not mistaken), it seems that it should follow that $K=K'$ and so that Eq-fibration morphisms should equivalent only if they are equal, which seems counterintuitive since the author proposes it as an equivalence alternative to equality.

So here is my question.

> Did I make any mistake in my argument above? In case not, how can the definition above be fixed to obtain a non trivial equivalence between Eq-fibration morphisms?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What is an Eq-fibration?

Comment: What page is that definition from?

Comment: Found it. My feeling is that the steps from $K\circ p(v)=K'\circ p(v)$ to $K=K'$ are suspect. At least at a quick glance, I can't see a property of the "classifying Eq-fibration" that would force $K$ and $K'$ to agree on *all* morphisms of $\mathbb B$. Though I may be the one missing things here.

Comment: @KevinCarlson - A fibred finite complete fibration with a finitely complete base category in which diagonal maps have left adjoints that satisfy the Frobenius identity.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine the only possible since $v$ has been chosen to be in the fiber of $u$ it follows the equality $K(u)=K'(u)$. The only possible problem I see could be that not all morphisms $u$ in the base category could be lifted but that would seem pretty strange.

Comment: If the fibre of $A\in\mathrm{Obj}(\mathbb{B})$ is empty, a morphism $\bullet\to A$ will have no Cartesian morphisms over it and has a lot more "wiggle room" over where $K$ or $K'$ send it. OTOH, if the fibre over $K(A)=K'(A)$ is non-empty, it seems like there might still be non-trivial internal equalities. But if this is what renders this notion of morphism Eq-fibration non-trivial, then we're saying it matters when we have types over which there are no predicates, which would be a very odd thing to say. I now share your skepticism.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine should I try to move this question to MathOverflow?

Comment: It's worth a shot, maybe. I came up blank on other users to tag about it, so it might be your best bet.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine then I'll repost it on MO, thanks.